# A native dll call consistently crashes one project in my solution but not the other (windows 7 64 bit)

Tags: c#, .net, lua, marshalling, unmarshalling

Basically I'm using lua (a native dll for scripting) from c#. I followed a tutorial to recompile the lua dll using the correct calling convention and import the needed functions.

There's a specific function that's crashing my program every time I call it. It takes a string from the native environment (which I put there earlier with a different api call) and returns it again as a managed string.

I have 3 seperate .net projects. The first project is a shared project that wraps up all the native calls nice and neat into a .net dll. The other two use the shared project. One is a GUI application using Windows.Forms and the other is a console application.

Everything works fine from the Console application, but every time I call that function I mentioned from the GUI project it crashes immediately without exceptions or erorr. I tried calling the function from the watch pane while debugging and it said: 'Function evaluation was abandoned' and a few seconds later the debugger exits.

I'm 100% positive that there is no difference in how I'm calling it from the GUI program and the console program, even though one works and the other doesn't. I should mention I'm developing primarily on windows 7 64 bit, but when I debugged on my laptop which is windows xp 32 bit the gui program mysteriously worked.

I suspect the problem has something to do with marshaling (which admittedly I know little about) or some other detail I'm unaware of. I do marshall the string as a UnmanagedType.LPStr before pushing into the native environment.

I'm not looking for a comprehensive answer or anything (though if you have one, by all means, lets hear it). I'm just looking for a bit of direction on how to go about fixing something like this.

Comment: This is quite inadequate information.  At least document what you see in the Output window.

Answer (score 2):

Check the platform target project settings of the Console and WinForms projects. I am certain, that one of them has "x86" and one has "Any CPU".

Comment: I remember having the same problem, and setting to x86 with 32bit Lua DLL was exactly the solution

Comment: Both projects are targeting x86. The offending function is lua_tolstring(). I'm passing it an IntPtr state, the index of a lua value that I tripled checked is a string, and IntPtr.Zero as the size pointer of the string. I really need to fix this because my entire project has ground to a hault.

I checked all the project properties I could and it seems the two are identical. The error I'm getting is: "Windows has triggered a breakpoint. This may be due to a corruption of the heap, which indicates a bug in MyGUIProgram.exe or any of the DLLs it has loaded." @DmitryLedentsov

Comment: @user1379635: You could strip down the GUI program until it stops crashing. Can you make a new WinForms project and get it to work? If not, you could upload that new crashing WinForms project along with a minimal console project that doesn't crash. Maybe someone else spots something.

Comment: I've discovered more and this is the weirdest thing I have ever seen while programming. Basically I have a function that pushes a string into lua and retrieves it with tolstring(). I call it from a button's event handler. Usually I call the function after popping open 2 dialog boxes to get info from the user and it fails. If I call the same function before I pop open the dialog boxes not only does that call work but even the call after the dailog boxes suddenly works. I'll work on stripping down the code to post later. Thanks for your assistance.

Comment: Narrowed down the problem to the FileDialog dialog box. If I comment that out and just hard-code the file path/name the program works as expected. Pretty weird. I'll get the code up tonight because I'm at work at the moment and I'm supposed to be doing other things.